# Redis GUI Tool with Cluster Support

Tags: user-interface, redis, cluster-computing, redis-cluster

Our project is in need of a **GUI** tool for monitoring and managing a Redis cluster.

I could not find one that has support for connecting to a **redis cluster**.

For example, I ran a redis cluster and a redis insight gui locally by `docker-compose` successfully:

```
services:
  redis-cluster:
    image: "grokzen/redis-cluster:latest"
    ports:
      - "7000-7007:7000-7007"
      - "5000-5002:5000-5002"
    environment:
      IP: "0.0.0.0"

  redisinsight:
    image: "redislabs/redisinsight:latest"
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
    - redisinsight:/db
```

But if I try to connect to the redis cluster by redis insight gui then it gives error:

[image]

If anyone's aware of this please let me know it will be really helpful :)

Thank You

Comment: Hello Dasun, what kind of feature related to cluster configuration would you like? (I'm Redsmin founder and we are currently working on the integration Redis Cluster support)

Answer (score -1):

Well our company just have made a web program for Redis clusters, not a desktop GUI program.

Here it is: https://github.com/HunanTV/redis-ctl

It can create clusters, make Redis join in or exit from the cluster, or migrates slots between the nodes via HTML forms. It displays Redis and cluster info in web pages prettily (well, perhaps not pretty, I'm not good at Javascript or CSS anyway).

But honestly speaking, it lacks documentation and manual. We're still working on it.

Feel free to leave your words at the issue page if you have any problems or suggestions.